# Using iTextSharp, how do I get an object if I have it's indirectReference

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp to analyze a form enabled PDF. I know how to navigate to the radio button control. I would like to analyze the individual radio buttons.

I have the PdfArray of the "kids" for the radio button. Each item in that array is a PdfIndirectReference. How do I get the actual object when all I have is the PdfIndirectReference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that `array` is the `PdfArray` object, then you have a complete series of methods to getg its elements. You're probably using the `Get()` method, but you should use the `GetDirectObject()` one of the `GetAsX()` methods. For instance:

```
PdfDictinary d = array.GetAsDict(0);
PdfArray a = array.GetAsArray(1);
PdfObject o = array.GetDirectObject(2);
```

Please start reading [this book](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc/) (unfinished, but free download) for more info.